# Efficient way to write a jQuery if statement for multiple items

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form that is using data-defaults and I need to be sure that they are cleared before submission. I have a jackhammer script that will do it, but I'm wondering if any of you would mind helping me finesse it.

The script below works and is perfectly fine if I want to write it for every input in the form (currently 8 with data defaults). I've tried selecting all of the inputs in the form with a few different approaches, but nothing seems to work. I imagine that there is a much smarter way to approach this than I am capable of, which is why I come here :)

```
$('#form_input_submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#specific_input_id').val() == $('#specific_input_id').attr('data-default')) {
      $('#specific_input_id').val('');
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: These are some great responses, I'm going to save off each of them to test later on! Thank you everyone, stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check all the input elements that have a default data element and clear those fields before submitting.

```
$('#tour_submit').click(function() {
    $('input[data-default]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default')) {
       $(this).val('');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is also an excellent answer. But you could do something similar on the onSubmit (.submit()...) rather than on the submit button click, and just return true.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all the inputs in the form, and iterate over them. If some are radio or select inputs, we'll need to change it a little.

```
$('#form_input_submit').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input').each(function() {
        if( this.value == $(this).attr('data-default') ) {
           this.value = '';
        }
    });
});
```

On the click of your `form_input_submit` button, it gets the `.closest()` ancestor `<form>`, and from there will `.find()` all the `<input>` elements.

Then it iterates over the collection using `.each()`.

If `$(this).attr('data-default')` represents the initial value of the input as it came from the server (or in any manner from its initial state), you could do this instead:

```
    if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
       this.value = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), simplifying your code down to this for all inputs:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
   $(this).find('[data-default]').val(function(i, v) {
      return $(this).data('default') == v ? "" : v;
    });
});
```

Also, instead of attaching to the `click` event of a submit button, this listens to the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the `<form>` itself.

Comment: This is a good answer, although a faster find would be: $(this).find('input[data-default]'), because it uses javascript's built in getElementsByTagName function. If you only search for [data-default], it will look through every single DOM element and select elements that have the data-default attribute causing the selector to be very very slow.

Comment: @Highway - Two things, you're restricting it to *only* `input` elements that way, what about `<textarea>` or `<select>` elements?  Also, jQuery will use `querySelectorAll()` when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the all the input items a class, then do this

```
$('#form_input_submit').click(function() {
    $('.inputs').each(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default')) {
          $(this).val('');
       }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Or you could just specify: $(this).find('input'), there's no need to assign a class to all the inputs. :)